# Can the vsphere apis be used on esx server without connectiong to the vsphere client

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esx

Using the vSphere Web Services SDK can the hard disks be added to the VM on a esx server without using any vsphere client.

Any links for the sample code to add the hard disks to VM would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What I know is the Vsphere Client also use the same sdk to invoke the operations Which we are doing from codes. So may be when we are running a code we are bypassing the vsphere client. (I may be wrong. Because what ever operation you do from code you can see the progress in Vsphere Client. Experts can comment on this.)

You can get an example of adding disks to VM @ [VmDiskOp.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/vijava/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/com/vmware/vim25/mo/samples/vm/VmDiskOp.java)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the vSphere Client SDK - you need the standard vSphere APIs. An easy way to start is using the vSphere management SDK -
 https://code.vmware.com/web/sdk/65/vsphere-management.